# drop out of bash script and get diverted to "endex"

Tags: bash

I have a script with this line in

```
read -t 1800 -n1 -p ""$bldgrn" Do you want to update the mpd feed? [y/n/q/r] $(tput sgr0)" ynqr
```

which drops out of the script after 30 minutes of inactivity. How can I get diverted to a function called "endex" please?

And "endex" is

```
function endex {
    echo;
    sleep 0;
    clear;
    exit
}
```

Comment: If `read` timeouts, its return code is greater than 128. So `if (($?>128)); then endex; else ...; fi` will do. Read `help read` for more info.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf were you planning on making that an answer, since it is one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `read` timeouts, its return code is greater than `128`. So

```
read -t 1800 -n 1 -p "${bldgrn}Do you want to update the mpd feed? [y/n/q/r]$(tput sgr0) " ynqr
if (($?>128)); then
    endex
else
    # no timeout here
fi
```

will do.

`help read` contains that information in the description of the `-t` option.

---

Make sure the `if (($?>128))` comes *just after* the read statement. If you need some intermediate commands, save the return code of `read`:

```
read -t 1800 -n 1 -p "blah blah"
saved_read_ret_code=$?
# Here you can do whatever you like
# ...
if ((saved_read_ret_code>128)); then
    echo "timeout"
else
    echo
    echo "no timeout"
fi
```

Comment: its not working! I've set it up as you've showed, run it and left it, but its not clearing the screen as part of 'endex', its just dropping out onto the same line. If i can do it, i'll amend my question so you can see 'endex'

Comment: @boudiccas: as a test, reduce your timeout, e.g., `-t 2` (for 2 seconds), an add `echo timeout` on a line just above the line `endex` to see if it's executed.

Comment: @boudiccas Can you run: `read -t 2; echo "$?"` in a terminal and also give me your bash version: `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`?

Comment: 142 and 4.3. just rebooted so I've got it without querying the version number :)

Comment: @boudiccas Then it works `:)`. You must have a typo somewhere. Look: `read -n 1 -t 5; if (($?>128)); then echo timeout; else echo; echo no timeout; fi`. Leave it for 5 seconds and you'll see `timeout` displayed, and if you hit a key before the 5 seconds you'll see `no timeout` displayed. What I suspect is that you put some commands between the `read` and the `if (($#>128))` line. Am I right? if it's the case I'll edit my answer to show you how to store the return code of `read`.

Comment: yes, i run  $(tput sgr0 at the end of the question before " if (($?>128)); then"

Comment: @boudiccas Well, in your question you run it _before_ the `read` statement, since it's inside the prompt string...

Comment: @boudiccas Edited the answer to show how to save the return code of `read` to use it later.